# Continuity of vector-valued function

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Z$ be two Banach spaces such that $Z\subset X$ with dense and continuous emmbedding. Let $\phi \in C([0,2],X)$(with respect to the norm of $X$) be a decreasing function such that $range(\phi)\subset Z$. Can we say that $\phi \in C([0,2],Z)$(with respect to the norm of $Z$) ? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a dense and continuous embedding? That $Z$ is embedded as a (topological) subspace of $X$ such that $\overline{Z} = X$? Is $Z$ assumed to be a linear subspace of $X$?

Comment: We mean by dense and continuous embedding that $Z$ is a dense subspace in $X$ and there is a constant $c>0$ such that for all $z \in Z$ we have $\|z\|_X≤c\|z\|_Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not true in general.

First notice that the condition that $t\mapsto\|\phi(t)\|$ does not really pose a restriction: Given $\phi\in C([0,2],X)$ with $\phi(t)\neq0$ for all $t\in[0,2]$ then $\psi(t):=\phi(t)/(\|\phi(t)\|+t)$ would also belong to $C([0,2],X)$ and $\|\psi(t)\|$ would be decreasing (by the compactness of $[0,2]$ the norm $\|\psi(t)\|$ is bounded from below). Then if $\phi\in C([0,2],Z)$ so is $\psi$. Hence, I will not care about this condition in the following example.

Take $X:=L^2(]0,2\pi[)$ and $Z:=H^1(]0,2\pi[)$ and $\phi(t)(x):=2+h(t)\sin(\frac{x}{h(t)^2})$ if $t\neq2$ and $\phi(2,x)=2$ with e.g. $h(t):=2-t$. Then $\phi(t)$ converges in $X$ to $\phi(2)$ but it diverges in $Z$ (taking $t_n=2-1/n$ should give $\|\phi(t_n)\|\rightarrow\infty$). Still $\phi(t)\in Z$ for all $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. The function given here is continuous except in 2. Can we construct a function that is not continuous in "many points" with respect to the norm of $Z$.

Comment: The function is continuous in with respect to $X$ but with respect to $Z$. As desired :-) !

Comment: Yes i know, but what if we consider the interval (0,2). I think this will be more difficult.

Comment: No, just do the same construction for the point 1 or any point within $(0,2)$ (instead of 2) and use e.g. a reflection.

Comment: What do you by not continuous in "many points"? Maybe you can update the question to describe exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: You cannot use the same construction if you want to obtain a discontinuity for example in 1, because if you do so, your function will not be continuous with respect to the $X$ norm. Anyway, thank you very much for your interaction with the question.

Comment: Are you sure? Take the $\phi\in C([0,2],X)$ as above and consider $\phi_1(t):=\phi(t+1)$ for $t\in(0,1]$ and $\phi_1(t):=\phi(3-t)$ for $t\in(1,2)$. Then $\psi_1(1)=\psi(2)$ and $\psi_1\in C((0,2),X) \setminus C((0,2),Z)$.